# What is the word that means a person has confused two terms with one another?

Tags: meaning

Is there a better verb than "confuse" in this passage:

> Joe has confused the terms A, B, and C. When describing B he used the attributes of A. Also, Joe used attributes of C when discussing A.

Comment: That highly technical term 'mixed up'.

Comment: I would suggest 'transposed' (but I think that specifically applies to numbers) or 'misappropriated' (to put to a wrong use).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, you may use 'conflate'. Conflate has a much better sense here than 'confuse' imo. Even though 'conflate' is defined as 'confuse' it has a secondary meaning of 'to bring together, to fuse'. The first meaning doesn't have a negative connotation, but the the second meaning of 'confusion' does (i.e. that you are conflating *in error* things that should not be conflated).

Answer (score 0):

**equivocate** means to describe something in an ambiguous way such that it may lead one into confusing one for the other.  This may be on purpose or by accident.  We don't know which Joe was doing, because the phrase itself is ambiguous as to his intent.